# Custom taxonomy page that lists content

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7, I'm trying to create a page that shows all terms in a specific taxonomy, along with node content that uses the taxonomoy.

What I'm hoping to do is create what's essentially a grid of views, where each term in the taxonomy displays: an image associated with the taxonomy term (the image field was added to this particular taxonomy), and then below it a list of nodes tagged with that term, ideally with each list having its own mini pager (although a complete listing or a partial listing with a "more" link would also work if a pager is not achievable).

I'd also like to do this without Panels, since I'm not using it anywhere else on the site.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I should approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way I know of is by using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
I would create a special "content type" with a special **image field**, a **text field** to describe the meaning of the Tag, and a **Term Reference field** to include the applicable tag later. Then I would enter one image + text for each existing tag and assign it to the tag itself. Later with the help of views I would customize display-views like the one you have mentioned which would take just a few minutes to do.

Comment: Ok, I can attach an image and a text field to a taxonomy term directly in Drupal 7 (by doing "Manage Fields" on the taxonomy itself). Unfortunately, I don't know where to go from there - when creating a view I can return taxonomy terms (where I can display the image and text, but not nodes with a particular tag), or I can display nodes with a particular tag, but then can't pull the image/text associated with the tag. Even then, I don't know how to display multiple views of that type on one page, even if I *could* make the appropriate view.

Comment: Learning to use Views is an extensive subject and it takes more than a paragraph to explain. I suggest to get a book about it and follow it from begin to end in order to grasp the whole concept. The one I'm most familiar with and I highly recommend is "Drupal 7 Essential Training" by Tom Geller which is a video course from Lynda.com